# Transforming R Base Plot into a Themed GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wondered if there exists a simple method for transforming base output in R into a nicer GGplot themed plot (such as theme_ipsum)?

Would appreciate any/all feedback on this given the PCA base plot example below.

```
install.packages("Gifi")
library(Gifi)

ABC6 <- ABC[,6:11]
fitord <- princals(ABC6)  
plot(fitord)
```

Comment: I think you need to redo the plot by figuring out what `plot.princals` does, and doing the equivalent in ggplot2.  No shortcuts.

Comment: "I wondered if there exists a simple method for transforming base output in R into a nicer GGplot themed plot (such as theme_ipsum)?"  Or, to put @user2554330's comment another way, "No, there does not".

Comment: In case someone is interested in trying, the source is `Gifi:::plot.princals`, online here:  https://github.com/cran/Gifi/blob/a2dd1d1bb47619d6e4bffac4571bfa080d392c4b/R/plot.princals.R#L1 . It's long because it does several different kinds of plots; each one is relatively simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ggplot2 function `autoplot` is an S3 generic that allows users to define a way of creating a ggplot automatically from an object of a particular class. Although the authors of Gifi have written a base R plot method (`Gifi:::plot.princals`) so that you can do `plot(fitord)`, they haven't written an `autoplot.princals` method to allow a ggplot to be created. However, it's not terribly difficult to do this yourself:

```r
library(tidyverse)

autoplot.princals <- function(x) {
  x$loadings %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    ggplot(aes(0, 0)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend = D1, yend = D2),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(3, "mm"))) +
    geom_text(aes(D1, D2 + ifelse(D2 > 0, 0.03, -0.03), label = rowname),
              hjust = 0) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "gray", linetype = 2) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "gray", linetype = 2) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(c(0.5 * -abs(x$loadings[,1]), x$loadings[,1])),
                             max(c(0.5 * abs(x$loadings[,1]),
                                   1.5 * x$loadings[,1])))) +
    labs(x = "Component 1", y = "Component 2") +
    hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum()
}
```

Which means we can simply do:

```r
autoplot(fitord)
```

[image]

And, to show this generalizes, we can do

```r
autoplot(princals(mtcars))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron. Really appreciate your help here. Great help :)